# Make a slider dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I would like to make a slider dynamic. I am using Slider Pro.

Here my structure :

jQuery

```
$(".item-0").mouseover(function () {
    $('#carousel').sliderPro('gotoSlide', 0);
});
$(".item-1").mouseover(function () {
    $('#carousel').sliderPro('gotoSlide', 1);
});
$(".item-2").mouseover(function () {
    $('#carousel').sliderPro('gotoSlide', 2);
});
$(".item-3").mouseover(function () {
    $('#carousel').sliderPro('gotoSlide', 3);
});
```

HTML :

```
<div class="slider-pro" id="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-menu">
        <a class="item-0" href="#carousel/0">
            <li>Yatching</li>
        </a>
        <a class="item-1" href="#carousel/1">
            <li>Aviation</li>
        </a>
        <a class="item-2" href="#carousel/2">
            <li>Automobile</li>
        </a>
        <a class="item-3" href="#carousel/2">
            <li>Watchmaking</li>
        </a>
    </ol>

    <div class="sp-slides">
        <!-- Slide 1 -->
        <div class="sp-slide">
            <img class="sp-image" src="path/to/image1.jpg" />
        </div>

        <!-- Slide 2 -->
        <div class="sp-slide">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </div>

        <!-- Slide 3 -->
        <div class="sp-slide">
            <h3 class="sp-layer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
            <p class="sp-layer">consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
        </div>

        <!-- Slide 4 -->
        <div class="sp-slide">
            <h3 class="sp-layer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
            <p class="sp-layer">consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like that on an hover on each "a" of the .item-0 we go to the slide 0, .item-1 go to the slide 1, .item-2 go to the slide 2 etc.... So I tried something more dynamic :

```
$('.item-' + i).each(function () {
    $(this).mouseover(function () {
        $('#carousel').sliderPro('gotoSlide', i);
    });
});
```

Comment: Use `index()` to get the current item index and use common class `index` on all the elements, `$(".item").mouseover(function () {
    $('#carousel').sliderPro('gotoSlide', $(this).index());
});`

Comment: @Tushar thank you. I don't need to specify .item-0, item-1 etc... on mouseover ?

Comment: Use common class `item` if you have styles written using `item-0`, then keep it otherwise remove it

Comment: Due to the structure of slider pro I can't use a common class ".item". :-(

Comment: You can use `$('[class^=item]')` selector to select all the elements whose class starts with `item`

Comment: @Tushar : Better put this as an answer since it will be helpful for other users.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use common class `item` to all the elements instead of `item-n`, if not possible you can use [**attribute starts with selector**](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) `$('[class^=item]')` to select all the elements whose class selects with `item`. I would also recommend to use it as `$('#carousel').find('[class^=item]')` to avoid selecting other matching elements on the page.
2. Instead of repeating the code for all the elements individually, add common event handler with [**index**](https://api.jquery.com/index/) as follow:

   ```
   $('[class^=item]').mouseover(function () {
       $('#carousel').sliderPro('gotoSlide', $(this).index());
   });
   ```